# How to "Save Game" using Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a tracker program of sorts, and i'm using a bunch of lists, but i can't save the values i'm putting into the lists. I need to save the lists in a way that i can run and re-run the program keeping the input values in the list.

Comment: You can either save them in a text file (.txt, .csv, etc) or pickle them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Asking Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular the part about [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us your code and outline explicitly what you've tried and what is not working.

Comment: Either what @KostasMouratidis said, or a database. SQLite is a good place to start for beginners.

Comment: You're looking for "serialization." See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464295/how-to-pickle-a-list)

Comment: if it's just lists [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is good too

Comment: @bobrobbob unless they're lists of arbitrary Python objects :) But yes, lists of strings, numbers, bools, and sublists of the same are perfect for JSON.