# Python - Add information to a list that is in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6

Refer to this program as File A:

```
vocabulary = []
while True:
   user_input = input('You: ')
   if user_input == 'vocabulary':
      print(vocabulary)
   vocabulary.append(user_input)
```

The thing is, I want the information being appended to `vocabulary` to be permanent, and not emptied every time I run the program. How can I do this?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html

Comment: Well, picking is possibly the easiest way to do it. How does the user exit the program?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use pickle to save your object ([How to pickle a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464295/how-to-pickle-a-list)) and then modifying it again etc.

Comment: This can not be a possible answer. It doesn't provide any valuable information rather than pointing at another question. You should make this a comment at best.

Answer (score 1):

Store `vocabulary` as an external file. Python's native filetype for storing and saving Python objects is a .pkl file (pickle) using the Pickle module.

I added an external file to your code sample, pickling the vocabulary variable.

```
import pickle, os

if os.path.isfile('pkl.pkl'):
    with open('pkl.pkl','rb') as p:
        vocabulary = pickle.load(p)
else:
    vocabulary = []
while True:
    user_input = input('You: ')
    if user_input == 'vocabulary':
        print(vocabulary)
    vocabulary.append(user_input)
    with open('pkl.pkl', 'wb') as p:
        pickle.dump(vocabulary, p)
```